# How to shed non-contiguous indices in c++/armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm looking for a clean way to shed non-contiguous indices in using the Armadillo linear algebra library for C++. I have some code included below, but it seems like there is probably a better way to do it. Any advice appreciated.

The following code works for removing indexes in `ind` from (column) vector `a`, but feels clunky.

```
for(uword k = ind.n_elem; k>0; k--){
        a.shed_row(ind(k-1));
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make a vector with indices of all the rows to keep and then extract the rows with [X.rows(indices)](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat)

Comment: Thanks @hbrerkere. The question then is how to cleanly go from a vector containing indexes to drop, `ind` (which is what I have), to a vector of indexes to keep, `indices` above. Ideas?

Comment: According to the documentation, you should be able to do `.shed_rows( vector_of_indices )`. But when I try this, I get a complaint that the second argument is missing. Searching for `shed_rows` in the documentation I find only `shed_rows(const uword in_row1, const uword in_row2)`. Maybe it's about to implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a templated function for dropping rows based on a (sorted) `uvec` of indexes to exclude. You get the missing indexes from `std::set_difference` and then go from there.

```
#define ARMA_USE_CXX11
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T drop_rows(T a, arma::uvec exclude) {
    arma::uvec full_range = arma::regspace<arma::uvec>(0, a.n_rows - 1);
    std::vector<int> diff;
    std::set_difference(full_range.begin(), full_range.end(), 
                        exclude.begin(), exclude.end(), 
                        std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
    T b = a.rows(arma::conv_to<arma::uvec>::from(diff));
    return b;
}

int main() {
    arma::uvec exclude = {0, 1, 4};

    arma::vec a = arma::linspace<arma::vec>(100, 500, 5);
    arma::vec b = drop_rows(a, exclude);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    arma::mat A = arma::mat(5, 5, arma::fill::eye);
    arma::mat B = drop_rows(A, exclude);
    std::cout << B << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```